# Is there a way to increase recording quality with the Web Audio API in Safari?

Tags: audio, safari, webrtc, audio-recording, web-audio-api

I'm using WebRTC along with [WebAudioRecorder.js](https://github.com/higuma/web-audio-recorder-js) and the Web Audio API to record microphone input from the user for audio recognition with the [audD API](https://api.audd.io/doc/) (similar to Shazam). This is working fine in Chrome and Firefox and it seems the quality of the recording is fairly solid. However, audD is not able to recognize the blob/file being sent from my recording in Safari (11.1.2) because of what I'm guessing is low audio quality (the playback is almost inaudible). The only audio format that both Safari and audD are compatible with is mp3, so that's how I've been encoding the file.

**Javascript:**

```js
// to be set to a WebAudioRecorder.js recorder instance
let recorder;
// to be set to the stream resulting from getUserMedia()
let gumStream;

function beginRecording() {
  if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    console.log('starting the recording');
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ 'audio': true })
    .then(function(stream) {


    let AudioContext = window.AudioContext // Default
        || window.webkitAudioContext // Safari and old versions of Chrome
        || false; 

    if (AudioContext) {
        let audioCtx = new AudioContext;
        gumStream = stream;
        let source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        recorder = new WebAudioRecorder(source, {
            workerDir: 'web-audio-recorder-js/lib/',
            encoding: 'mp3'
        });

    } else {
        alert('The Web Audio API is not supported.');
    }

      recorder.setOptions({
        timeLimit: 120,
        encodeAfterRecord: true,
        ogg: {quality: 0.9},
        mp3: {bitRate: 320},
      });

      recorder.startRecording();

      recorder.onComplete = function(recorder, blob) {
        createAudioPlayback(blob);
        POSTreq(blob);
      }
      
      recorder.onError = function(recorder, err) {
        console.error(err);
      }

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    })
  }
}

function stopRecording() {
  console.log('stopping the recording');
  let recordingTime = recorder.recordingTime();
  console.log(recordingTime);

  let audioTrack = gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0];
  console.log(audioTrack);

  audioTrack.stop();

  recorder.finishRecording();

  $('#msg_box').text(`Recorded for ${Math.round(recordingTime)} seconds`);
  console.log('recording stopped');
}

function createAudioPlayback(blobData) {
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
  $('body').append(`<audio controls src="${url}"></audio>`);
}

function POSTreq (blobData) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('api_token', '');
  fd.append('file', blobData);
  fd.append('method', 'recognize');
  fd.append('return_itunes_audios', true);
  fd.append('itunes_country', 'us');

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      parseRetrievedData(xhr.response);
    }
  }
  xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.audd.io/');
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.send(fd);
}

function parseRetrievedData(parseData) {
  console.log('the data from the audD api is: ', parseData);
}

$(function() {
  $('#start-button').click(function(e) {
    beginRecording();
    $('#stop-button').prop('hidden', false);
  });
  $('#stop-button').click(function(e) {
    stopRecording();
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="recorder_wrapper">
        <div class="recorder">
            <button id="start-button">Start</button>
            <button id="stop-button">Stop</button>
            <p id="msg_box"></p>
            <section class="auth-links-region" role="region">
              <a href="#" class="auth-link signup">Signup</a>
              <a href="#" class="auth-link login">Login</a>
            </section>
            <section class="authentication-region" role="region" hidden>
              <p class="authentication-text"></p>
              <a href="#" class="mysearches-link">My Searches</a>
              <a href="#" class="logout-link">Logout</a>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you using the same computer for all of the recordings?

Comment: Yes. The same computer's microphone. I guess the result would vary depending on the user's device, but I think it's an issue with how Safari is either recording or encoding the audio data.